# How to extend Webpack config in Cypress 10+

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to extend the Webpack config in Cypress 10.8.0, but the only documentation I could find refers to the "legacy plugin file": https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/master/npm/webpack-preprocessor#modifying-default-options

I suppose there is a way to do this directly in the `cypress.config` file, but how?

Answer (score 8):

I actually ended up finding how (probably the Cypress documentation should be updated at some point). Here is an example to "Polyfill" the `node:` prefixed modules:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import webpackPreprocessor from "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor";
import Webpack from "webpack";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000",
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      const options = webpackPreprocessor.defaultOptions;
      options.webpackOptions.plugins = options.webpackOptions.plugins ?? [];
      options.webpackOptions.plugins.push(
        new Webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
          /^node:/,
          (resource: { request: string }) => {
            resource.request = resource.request.replace(/^node:/, "");
          }
        )
      );

      on("file:preprocessor", webpackPreprocessor(options));
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Hm. I get `Cannot find module '@cypress/webpack-preprocessor' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`.

Comment: Did you install the package? I dont think its bundled with Cypress

Comment: Strange, because webpack is the default bundler in Cypress.

Comment: You actually need to install `@cypress/webpack-preprocessor` which is a package maintained by Cypress